# iOS 4 Application Termination and Undo

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, nsundomanager

What is a good way to handle iOS 4 app termination when using an `NSUndoManager`?

I have an iPhone (iOS 4) application that uses Core Data. The app allows the user to edit managed objects, and I implement undo using `NSUndoManager` in a straightforward manner: Before displaying an editor view modally, I create a new `NSUndoManager` for the managed object context. I also begin undo grouping so that any changes can easily be undone if the user taps the "Cancel" button. If the user taps "Save," I simply remove the undo manager and the changes become permanent. So far, so good.

If the user presses the Home button (or takes a call) in the midst of editing an object, the app gets suspended. It sends the app delegate an `applicationDidEnterBackground` message and I use that opportunity to save the managed object context. The context, of course, contains the new edits, just waiting to be undone by the `NSUndoManager`.

Here's the issue: If the app is later "unsuspended," the `NSUndoManager` still exists and everything works fine. However, if the app gets "killed in its sleep" by the OS, the undo stack is lost and the changes made to the object now become permanent. At relaunch I want to restore the app to the exact same state it was in before it was suspended, but that seems to require me to save and restore the undo stack. Unfortunately, I couldn't find an obvious way to do that.

Is there a good way to support undo so that it works consistently whether or not an app is terminated? I hope I'm missing something obvious. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can spend all the time in the world serializing your current app state to disk so you can relaunch where you left off...

... or you can sidestep the issue by reducing your memory footprint so you're less likely to be killed while in the background. I suspect the backgrounded-due-to-phonecall app is given priority over other background apps, if only because it is more recently used.

Low memory, updating the app, or tapping the box in the task switcher can all kill your app. It's up to you to decide whether you need to preserve the *exact state* the app was in. I think Android only preserves the serialized app state for about 30 minutes, because short-term memories don't tend to last much longer.

(What? .foo.txt.swp exists? It's several months old! How am I supposed to know where it's from? Why can't you just show me the changes between that and foo.txt so I can decide whether I want to keep it?)

Comment: Good point. If I understand correctly, you're essentially saying this: If an app has a small memory footprint when suspended, it's likely to last longer than the user's ability to remember what they were doing. It's hard to argue with that. I'm still hoping there's a relatively simple way to keep my app in control of whether/when undoable actions become permanent, but I get that providing "month-old undo" is probably of limited benefit to most users.

Comment: Well paraphrased. There doesn't seem to be a documented way of getting the current state out of NSUndoManager, so I don't think it's expected behaviour.

Comment: I didn't find anything either. Thanks for your help.